# SQL insert into table not working

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to insert status update into my database in table called blabbing, but it's not working.

my php code

```
$thisRandNum = rand(9999999999999,999999999999999999);
$_SESSION['wipit'] = base64_encode($thisRandNum); // Will always overwrite itself each time this script runs

// ------- POST NEW BLAB TO DATABASE ---------
$blab_outout_msg = "";
if (isset($_POST['status']) && $_POST['status'] != "" && $_POST['status'] != " "){

     $blabWipit = $_POST['blabWipit'];
     $sessWipit = base64_decode($_SESSION['wipit']);
     if (!isset($_SESSION['wipit'])) {

     } else if ($blabWipit == $sessWipit) {

          // End Delete any blabs over 20 for this member
         $status = $_POST['status'];
         $status = stripslashes($status);
         $status = strip_tags($status);
         $status = mysql_real_escape_string($status);
         $status = str_replace("'", "&#39;", $status);
         $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO blabbing (mem_id, profile_id, the_blab, blab_date) VALUES('$logOptions_id','$logOptions_id','$status', now())");
         $blab_outout_msg = "";
         }

}
```

my html code

```
<div style="background-color:#f2f2f2; border:#ebebeb 1px solid; padding:8px;">
    <form action="home.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="blab_from">
    <textarea name="status" id="status" rows="3" style="width:99%;"></textarea>
    <input name="submit" type="submit" class="btn" value="Blab" /> &nbsp; &nbsp; Limit:  <script>displaylimit("","status",255)</script>
     <input name="blabWipit" type="hidden" value="<? print $thisRandNum;?>" />
    </form>
    </div>
```

any help appreciated

Comment: there is no error message, it's just doesn't insert for some reason.

Comment: Do you have error reporting turned on? Add `error_reporting(E_ALL)` before the mysql call.

Comment: Are you in `auto-commit` mode? try executing `mysql_query( 'commit' );` right after the insert.  Oh, and did you `echo` alongside the query to make sure that the insert code gets executed??

Comment: it's still doesn't display any error related to my problem.

Comment: Just a note...Change this part: `&& $_POST['status'] != "" && $_POST['status'] != " ")` to `&& trim($_POST['status']) != "")`

Comment: for some reason it doesn't pass the first IF STATEMENT

Comment: thank, cillosis for your suggestion. tried that, still not working.

Comment: If a MySQL query fails, there will always be a reason and you can get an error message with `mysql_error()`. Add something like this after your `mysql_query`-call: `if ($sql == false) echo mysql_error()` for debugging purposes and instead of `echo` do some logging for production. Failing MySQL queries do not trigger PHP errors so playing with `error_reporting` won't do a thing.

Comment: Split up the compound IF statement, with its dodgy precedence and bracket-shortage, into three IF's so you can see which one is failing, if any.

Comment: Also check your tables default values. If you are using VARCHAR fields with an inadequate length, your query will fail.

Comment: lol `rand(9999999999999,999999999999999999)` epic fail

Comment: Does it work if you directly commit the query into database? What does your table structure look like? You are inserting the `$logOptions_id` into two different columns so if they have for example unique index the query will fail. In that case you should get an error message. Are you keeping history of status changes or do you need only current status? In that case you should use update statement into existing row. I'm guessing your `mem_id` and `profile_id` aren't `auto_increment` columns so our query will fail after first insert if you don't have additional PK column with AI in use.

Comment: You should use params or at least mysql_real_escape_string() to sanitize your database input.

Comment: @Francisc He does, excessively.

Comment: I see no params and he only uses mysql_real_escape_string() for `$status`.

Comment: You also don't see that he doesn't, as he did not include the other variable's definitions. I think from his one sanitization you can assume that he sanatized the rest, as well. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$thisRandNum = rand(9999999999999,999999999999999999);
$_SESSION['wipit'] = base64_encode($thisRandNum); // Will always overwrite itself each time this script runs

// ------- POST NEW BLAB TO DATABASE ---------
$blab_outout_msg = "";
if (isset($_POST['status']) && $_POST['status'] != "" && $_POST['status'] != " "){

     $blabWipit = $_POST['blabWipit'];
     $sessWipit = base64_decode($_SESSION['wipit']);
    // if (!isset($_SESSION['wipit'])) {

     //} else if ($blabWipit == $sessWipit) {

          // End Delete any blabs over 20 for this member
         $status = $_POST['status'];
         $status = stripslashes($status);
         $status = strip_tags($status);
         $status = mysql_real_escape_string($status);
         $status = str_replace("'", "&#39;", $status);
         $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO blabbing (mem_id, profile_id, the_blab, blab_date) VALUES('$logOptions_id','$logOptions_id','$status', now())");
         $blab_outout_msg = "";
       //  }

}
```

Try this if it works then `else if ($blabWipit == $sessWipit) {` this condition is not true